# Vuetify autocomplete similar items are not showing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-model

I have custom posts with similar title in my case from my local **API** and I've tried to show posts by search query from `items` array.

**Data:**

```
{
    "count": 5,
    "entries": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Senior developer Python"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "Senior developer Python"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "Senior developer Python"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Vuetify autocomplete code:**

```
  <v-autocomplete
    v-model="model"
    :items="items"
    :loading="isLoading"
    :search-input.sync="search"
    color="white"
    hide-no-data
    hide-selected
    item-text="Description"
    item-value="API"
    return-object
  ></v-autocomplete>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      descriptionLimit: 60,
      entries: [],
      isLoading: false,
      model: null,
      search: null
    }),

    computed: {
      items () {
        return this.entries.map(entry => {
          const Description = entry.title.length > this.descriptionLimit
            ? entry.title.slice(0, this.descriptionLimit) + '...'
            : entry.title

          return Object.assign({}, entry, { Description })
        })
      }
    },

    watch: {
      search (val) {  
        // Items have already been requested
        if (this.isLoading) return

        this.isLoading = true

        // Lazily load input items
        fetch('https://api.website.org/posts')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            const { count, entries } = res
            this.count = count
            this.entries = entries
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          })
          .finally(() => (this.isLoading = false))
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

How I can show in my autocomplete all similar posts by title also?

Comment: I don't understand how does the user differentiate between identical texts? you just want them to appear a few times?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to set `item-value` to `id` like :

```
 <v-autocomplete
    v-model="model"
    :items="items"
    :loading="isLoading"
    :search-input.sync="search"
    color="white"
    hide-no-data
    hide-selected
    item-text="Description"
    item-value="id"
    return-object
  ></v-autocomplete>
```

check [`this pen`](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/MWQZZRR)

Comment: link is not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

Note that autocompletes also tries to find exact matches in your items. Perhaps for server side suggestions you should use the `v-combobox`.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to turn this functionality off? I expect the autocomplete component to show all items in the result set, perhaps I am misunderstanding the component.