# Vuetify Autocomplete only show first result

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuetify.js

When i trigger search method to update the item list, if it load 3 results for example, in the autocomplete only show the first result

[image]
[image]

It only show more than 1 result when the item list is bigger than 100 (more or less)

```
    <v-autocomplete
                box
                v-model="vproveedor"
                :items="itemsAnexos"
                :loading="isLoading"
                :search-input.sync="search"
                hide-no-data
                hide-selected
                item-text="anexDescripcion"
                item-value="anexRuc"
                label="Proveedor"
                placeholder="Busque un proveedor"
                return-object
                >
</v-autocomplete>

<script>
  data: () =>({

        itemsAnexos:[],
        vproveedor:null,
        isLoading: false,
        search: null,
    }),
    watch: {
      search(val) {
        if(!val) this.itemsAnexos = []
        if(!val || this.isLoading || val.length < 3) return

        this.isLoading = true
        axios.get('anexos',{
          params: {
            anexDescripcion : val
          }})
          .then(res => this.itemsAnexos = res.data)
          .finally(() => (this.isLoading = false))
        console.log(this.itemsAnexos)

      },
    },
</script>
```

Comment: I solve my problem with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57038191/vuetify-autocomplete-similar-items-not-showing/57038348

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuetify autocomplete similar items are not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57038191/vuetify-autocomplete-similar-items-are-not-showing)